# Problem with pushing into stack with generic type

Tags: c++, generics, stack

I'm trying to push an object into a stack, and get an error compiling it.
(I did the same with a queue and it works perfectly, but i need the stack for implementing DFS).

Generic object 'T' is replaced with 'pair(int, int)'.

Dfs.h:

```
//Inculdes...
template<class T>
class Dfs : public Searcher<T> {
 private:
  AlgoStack<State<T>*> stack;
 public:
  vector<State<T>*> search(Searchable<T> *searchable) {
    State<T> *start = searchable->getStartPoint();
    stack.push(start);
//code....
}
```

AlgoStack.h:

```
//Inculdes...
template <class T>
class AlgoStack : public DataManager<T>{
 private:
  stack<State<T>*> myQ;
 public:
  void push(State<T>* temp) override {
    myQ.push(temp);
  }
```

The error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘AlgoStack<State<std::pair<int, int>* >>::push(State<std::pair<int, int> >*&)’
     stack.push(start);
```

Comment: Please provide [mre].

Comment: templates are just templates. You need some steps more to get the error you report. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You've got minimal nailed. You can stop on that end, but reproducible requires a program that we can feed into a compiler and get the same result.  Right now we just get something like https://ideone.com/jsDmHx and we can't do jack to solve your problem with that.

Comment: Do not call your variable `stack`.  There is a `std::stack` class already existing in the `std` namespace.

Comment: you say `T== pair<int,int>` but the error says `T== State<pair<int,int>>*`. The problem is how you instantiate the template and then use it, ie the part you do not show

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "_Do not call your variable `stack`. There is a `std::stack` class already existing in the `std` namespace._" Unless one does `using namespace std;` - I see no problem in naming variable as `stack`. Namespaces solve exactly this issue (of possible name collisions).

Comment: ...uhm well actually there are two different `T`s in the code you posted. I am really not good at quizzes

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius OP seems to have both. There is `stack<State<T>*> myQ;` and `stack.push(start);`.

Comment: let my try to explain why you should have posted a [mcve]. The code you posted is not sufficient to get the error message you report, so you obviously have more code. Now the problem is that whatever code you have in addition I am certain that I could add more code to make the error vanish. This is especially true when templates are involved. My answer can only be a guess, but I have no way to know for sure what really caused the error, as such this Q&A is unlikely to be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question misses important details and actually I shouldnt be writing this answer, but as you actually also didnt ask a question, I just do it.

This error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘AlgoStack<State<std::pair<int, int>* >>::push(State<std::pair<int, int> >*&)’
```

tells us that there is an instantiation of `AlgoStack` with the template parameter being `State<std::pair<int, int>*`:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘AlgoStack<State<std::pair<int, int>* > > ...
                                                   ^--------------------------^
```

and the compiler needs that to have a `push` accepting a `State<std::pair<int, int> >*&`:

```
error: [...]>>::push(State<std::pair<int, int> >*&)
                     ^---------------------------^
```

Now lets look at the template:

> ```
> //Inculdes...
> template <class T>
> class AlgoStack : public DataManager<T>{
>  private:
>   stack<State<T>*> myQ;
>  public:
>   void push(State<T>* temp) override {
>     myQ.push(temp);
>   }
> ```

The instantiation mentioned in above error (`AlgoStack<State<std::pair<int, int>* > >`) has a

```
push( State< State<std::pair<int,int>* >* temp)
```

but not the overload you are trying to call. I suppose there is one level of `State` too much and you can remove one of them.